# Golang modules: Import proto definitions

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, go-modules

I am trying to learn Go modules dependency manager but getting an error while importing auto-generated proto definitions. Have been struggling with this for 2 days. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Directory structure:

```
➜  ~/go-service-skeleton> tree .
.
├── protobuf
│   └── test_service
│       ├── test_service_config.pb.go
│       └── test_service_config.proto
├── src
│   └── test_service
│       ├── go.mod
│       ├── main.go
│       └── server
│           └── server.go
```

Error (last error is particularly concerning):

```
➜  ~/go-service-skeleton/src/test_service go build
bootstrap.go:11:2: no required module provides package github.com/Sirupsen/logrus; to add it:
    go get github.com/Sirupsen/logrus
bootstrap.go:12:2: no required module provides package github.com/sirupsen/logrus; to add it:
    go get github.com/sirupsen/logrus
bootstrap.go:13:2: no required module provides package gopkg.in/yaml.v2; to add it:
    go get gopkg.in/yaml.v2
server/server.go:8:2: package protobuf/test_service is not in GOROOT
```

```
~/go-service-skeleton/src/test_service echo $GOPATH
/Users/****/go-service-skeleton:/Users/****/go-service-skeleton/protobuf
~/go-service-skeleton/src/test_service echo $GOROOT
```

Comment: You haven’t added your dependencies to `go.mod`, and you proto files are not in your module, so go cannot find them.

Comment: that was it @JimB. as soon as I moved the proto files under the module, it went through. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your `test_service` module, the only dependencies visible to the `go` command are the ones declared in its `go.mod` file.

The simplest fix is to put all of the source code you need inside the main module. Note that per https://blog.golang.org/generate, “if the containing package is intended for import by `go get`, once the file is generated (and tested!) it must be checked into the source code repository to be available to clients.”